# Dropbox get public url of the file after upload

Tags: php, dropbox

Need to upload files to dropbox and get the public url of that file. I'am generating thumbnails and need to show that in my site. I should also show the original files to users without login to the dropbox site.

After uploading to dropbox I need to get the original file url which will be used by crocodoc api viewer.

I could able to upload the file and I am getting the metadata of that file. I created shared url and given that url that url img tag in html but seems returning as html instead of image.

I have gone through similar questions mentioned in SO but almost all are referring old documents.

Comment: We can't help you without you providing the code you've tried and the *exact* issue you're facing. To me, this question can be worded "Give me the code to problem X" and it will mean the same.

Comment: It sounds like you may be referring to Dropbox shared links, which by default give a HTML preview page. You can find information on modifying these links for different uses here: https://www.dropbox.com/help/201

Answer (score 2):

I found this trick earlier and thought I'd share.

Go to: https://www.dropbox.com/home

Then, highlight your mouse over an item, click on share.
[image]
This will popup:
[image]

Simply change:

`https://www.dropbox.com/s/io9oz94lgm2j2bb/loadingscreen.jpg?dl=0`

to

`https://dl.dropbox.com/s/io9oz94lgm2j2bb/loadingscreen.jpg`

Replacing the `www` with `dl`, to get the direct, *public* url.

Comment: Thanks for this useful solution.