# How to get the size of an image from a url in php?

Tags: php, image, size

I've been trying to get the size of an image from a url, but it's not working. Can anyone help me?

This is the code:

```
$imagesize = getimagesize('https://www.dropbox.com/s/hbtmge2omlyqx2n/BrownBag.jpg?dl=0');
echo $imagesize;
```

Comment: Check `ini_get('allow_url_fopen')` is on.

Comment: Also, return value is array... echo $array is not good

Comment: @marekful I've checked it, and the answer is 1. What does that mean?

Comment: It won't work because Dropbox is protecting itself from using it as image sharing site. What you have is not actual image address but address for page which dynamically generates image view (with controls and so on).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You're not getting the image https://www.dropbox.com/s/hbtmge2omlyqx2n/BrownBag.jpg?dl=0
 in this url

What you need to get is the **image address** which is this
https://photos-5.dropbox.com/t/2/AADa4bq7fis50BvRTojhB5zvAJDLNwsLDb5dekkb4JfilQ/12/502094097/jpeg/32x32/3/1513760400/0/2/BrownBag.jpg/EJrFv4kEGLgCIAIoAg/cwCCXcZopeYId4BrstNKJ6qGETjrin47oEgU6B50AE0?dl=0&size=1280x960&size_mode=3

**Code**

```
$imagesize = getimagesize('https://photos-5.dropbox.com/t/2/AADa4bq7fis50BvRTojhB5zvAJDLNwsLDb5dekkb4JfilQ/12/502094097/jpeg/32x32/3/1513760400/0/2/BrownBag.jpg/EJrFv4kEGLgCIAIoAg/cwCCXcZopeYId4BrstNKJ6qGETjrin47oEgU6B50AE0?dl=0&size=1280x960&size_mode=3');
print_r($imagesize);
```

**Result**

```
Array
(
    [0] => 1000
    [1] => 750
    [2] => 2
    [3] => width="1000" height="750"
    [bits] => 8
    [channels] => 3
    [mime] => image/jpeg
)
```

You can also refer to this [Dropbox get public url of the file after upload](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29895048/dropbox-get-public-url-of-the-file-after-upload)

Simply change:

```
https://www.dropbox.com/s/hbtmge2omlyqx2n/BrownBag.jpg?dl=0
```

to

```
https://dl.dropbox.com/s/hbtmge2omlyqx2n/BrownBag.jpg
```

Just replace `www` with `dl` and remove `?dl=0`

Comment: I will, Thank you once again :D

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the image path of dropbox

```
$imagesize = getimagesize('https://photos-5.dropbox.com/t/2/AADa4bq7fis50BvRTojhB5zvAJDLNwsLDb5dekkb4JfilQ/12/502094097/jpeg/32x32/3/1513760400/0/2/BrownBag.jpg/EJrFv4kEGLgCIAIoAg/cwCCXcZopeYId4BrstNKJ6qGETjrin47oEgU6B50AE0?dl=0&size=1600x1200&size_mode=3');
echo $imagesize;
```